# Hide other datepicker selections ios

Tags: ios, datepicker

The date picker I have right now looks like the picture below:

[image]

I want it to look like this:
[image]

I want to hide the grey selections, and only show the current selections.
Two possible solutions I have thought of are to
1: Change the grey font color to white, but to my understanding you cant change the font of UIDatePicker.

2: Add an image over the datepicker, and set the datePicker subview behind it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you get the solution?